# Hi, I am using visual basic and the error says 'Conversion from string "Integer is not valid." to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MsgBox()
        Input("Are you an employee or a customer: ")
        If Name = "employee" Then
            Name = Input("first 2 letters of first name:")
            Dim number As Object
            number = input(str("Year enter of company exc 20: "))
        ElIf Name = "customer" Then
            Name = Input("Enter email: ")
            Dim password As Object
            password = Input("Enter password: ")
            Dim username As String
            username = Name
        Else
            Print("Incorrect. Try again.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

This code is to make a login on visual basic using the button tool so it can go to another page

Comment: It appears you're using VB6 compatibility in VB.NET. `MsgBox()` is VB6, `MessageBox.Show()` is VB.NET. Don't declare every variable as `Object`; use a proper data type. Follow @David's guidance in his answer.

Comment: There is no overload of `MsgBox` that has no parameters. Try to get used to the .net way, `MessageBox.Show.`

There is an `Input` method in VisualBasic.FileSystem but there is no overload the accepts a single `String` as a parameter. I don't think that is what you are intending here.


Don't declare variables as `Object` unless absolutely necessary. Find out what the `Function` returns and declare accordingly.

Why do you have a variable `Name` and `username`? Just use one or the other.

Comment: What is` ElIf`?

Comment: Where and how is `Name` declared? With the `Str` function, why are you converting a `String` to a `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you create a desktop application and not leverage any of the controls? You would be better off creating a form that has:

1. Two RadioButtons to distinguish login type
2. Two TextBox controls
3. One NumericUpDown control

When the user changes their login type selection, it would dynamically hide/show one of the TextBox controls and the NumericUpDown control. Take a look at this screenshot:
[image: document outline screenshot]

Now in the RadioButton's CheckedChanged event, you would change the label's text and toggle the visibility of the controls:

```vb
Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    Label1.Text = If(RadioButton1.Checked, "Email", "First 2 letters of first name")
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    TextBox2.MaxLength = If(RadioButton1.Checked, Integer.MaxValue, 2)
    TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
    TextBox2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
    Label2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
    NumericUpDown1.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
    Label3.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
End Sub
```

Finally, when the user clicks on login you can get the values based on the login type using the NumericUpDown to get a numeric value:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (RadioButton1.Checked) Then
        ' customer login
        Dim customerName = TextBox1.Text
        Dim password = TextBox2.Text

    Else
        ' employee login
        Dim employeeName = TextBox1.Text
        Dim number = Decimal.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much i am still inexperienced and this has been very helpful thank you for all this

Comment: @Aya , The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. Do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.